# Take the space out of file names and or replace character with something else

Tags: c#

Im trying to remove the spaces out of a bunch of file names(pdf's in a directory). I have tried the following. both input and output directories are folderbrowserdialog box's

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())
{
     try
     {
        File.Copy(file.FullName, outputDir + @"\" + file.Replace(" ", "_"));        
     }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Im sorry...the question is how do you remove spaces from a file name? The error i was getting with this code was "The path is not of a legal form".

Comment: Thanks for all the quick reply ladies and gents. its much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the file name out of the file info object:

```
file.Name.Replace(" ", "_")
```

Use `Path.Combine` to put the path together (more robust across different systems):

```
Path.Combine(outputDir, file.Name.Replace(" ", "_"))
```

So:

```
di = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
foreach (var file in di.GetFiles()) {
  try {
    File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(outputDir, file.Name.Replace(" ", "_")));                     
  }
```

Comment: You the man. that was it. I was missing the combine step. thanks a million for that fast solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())
{
    try
    {
        File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(outputDir, Path.GetFileName(file.FullName).Replace(" ", "_")));
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Copy(file.FullName, outputDir + @"\" + file.Name.Replace(" ", "_"));
```